# $K_{3,3}$ is not a proper subgraph of a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

I am trying to prove: Except for $K_{3,3}$ itself, no expansion (aka [subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing)) of $K_{3,3}$ is a supergraph of $K_{3,3}$.

Does the following look valid? Is there a better solution?

**Proof**: Suppose there was such a (proper) supergraph with a single vertex expanded. Then, for any selection of 6 vertices we can make there are two cases to consider:

- Case 1: We chose 6 vertices, none of which is an expanded vertex of degree 2. In this case, we have $v = 6$ and $e = 8$, which cannot be isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$.
- Case 2: We chose 6 vertices, at least one of which is a vertex of degree 2, which means it cannot be isomorphic $K_{3,3}$.

In cases where there are more than one expansion, we have two similar cases: We either end up with $e \leq 8$ or vertices of degree two.

Therefore, no such supergraph exists.

Comment: @SK19 I think because by supposition, none of the vertices are of degree two. Since we are looking at an expansion of $K_{3,3}$, it must edges must therefore have degree 3 unless they were attached to a vertex of degree 2 we did not select. I was thinking maybe this all boils down to the case where there is only a single expansion, in which case we have 8 edges by simply counting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking we need to restrict to the case where there is only one additional subdivision, in which case $e = 8$ holds. Then, I guess any further subdividing really just makes matters worse, so any 6 vertices we select will have <= 8 edges or contains vertices of degree 2. I updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Ah yes, I miscounted, sorry. Time for bed.

Comment: @SK19 No worries, I think you were right and I had an implicit assumption :)